# Grails including null value check in searchable query builder

Tags: grails, query-builder, grails-searchable

We are using grails 2.1.1 and searchable - 0.6.3

We are trying to filter results using `query builder`. Our problem is that we cannot put a check on tupples having null in a field. We have gone through lots of documentation but couldn't find any solution.

Is there a way to put a `null value check` using query builder in `grails searchable plugin`.

using

```
mustNot(term('columnName',null))
```

or

```
mustNot(term('columnName','null'))
```

does not work.

Comment: The way we solved this was to map the null values to something like -1 or something while indexing and exclude -1 in query builder

Comment: Could you put more detail of your solution in as an answer. This is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

mustNot(gt("columnName", 0))